# Why is "more than meets the eye" grammatical in some cases?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, phrases, phrasal-verbs, grammaticality-in-context

I find this idiom very interesting, idiomatic and intuitive but not that grammatical to me. Why should we use `meet`s, the third-person singular simple present sense? Can I change it to any other senses?

For instance in this sentence from [idioms.thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/more+than+meets+the+eye):

> A hidden significance, greater than is first apparent, as in this
>   agreement involves more than meets the eye.

can the `meets` be changed to `meet` if I make the following changes(make the singular a plural)?

> A hidden significance, greater than is first apparent, as in these
>   **agreements** involve more than **meet** the eye.

Is the following also grammatical?

> A hidden significance, greater than is first apparent, as in these
>   **agreements** involve more than **meets** the eye.

Or it is independent of all other elements in the sentence and fixed?

Comment: I'd use the singular "involves" here, which matches up with the singular subject "a hidden significance".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Because it is an idiom, and we do not "adapt" idioms.
2. If I am not wrong,

> more than meets the eye

is the shorter form of

> more than **what** meets the eye

Since "what" has the value of a singular, it requires a verb in singular, even if it ("what") is missing.

Comment: Roughly. I would say, rather, that "more" is a here a pronoun, and is singular.